# Remove useless files from a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation, maintenance

I want to find a way to delete all the useless files: binaries, log and cache files, duplicate files and app's leftover.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

## [Onyx (free)](http://www.titanium.free.fr/download.php?sid=0c5803d09bf388f117c6541230f533e8)

- Verify the Startup Disk and the structure of its System files, to run misc. tasks of system maintenance
- Configure some hidden parameters of the Finder, Dock, QuickTime, Safari, Mail, iTunes, Login window, Spotlight, and many of Apple’s applications
- Delete caches, to remove a certain number of files and folders that may become cumbersome, and more.
- ...

Removing duplicate files is not supported by Onyx.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use Macaroni by Atomic Bird http://www.atomicbird.com.  Cost $10.  Installs as a login item, with a pane in System Preferences.  Automatic daily, weekly and monthly cleaning.

2014: I would also recommend "Duplicate Detective", currently $3 in the Mac App Store.  It finds files with duplicate hash values, not relying on file names or just file sizes alone.

Answer (score 1):

One of the oldest and popular app is CCleaner. It is most popular app for PC. And it works perfectly on Mac too.

- https://www.piriform.com/mac/ccleaner

Answer (score -4):

I use [CleanMyMac](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac), which has the following [features](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac/features):

- reset outdated cache files to zero
- remove log files
- remove the binary files that are not executed on your computer, from applications with an executable for PowerPC and Intel
- remove useless files created by applications
- remove leftovers, and clean the trashcan
- keep the trashcan under control, and delete the files when the size of the files contained in the trashcan reach a limit you can set
- uninstall applications

  [image: screenshot]

Comment: Not sure why you were voted down. I use an application called MacKeeper which is quite similar.

Comment: I'd also like an explanation for the downvote.

Comment: Having used both CleanMyMac and MacKeeper, I have to say they are both dubious applications. They run constantly, and are *extremely* hard to remove.

Comment: I downvoted for 3 reasons. One was touched on by @spudwaffle: the product is not entirely safe. The second is because the guys that run MacPaw (makers of CleanMyMac) exploit the review system of sites like MacUpdate to artificially inflate their rankings (by giving out licenses in exchange for favorable reviews). Therefore, it's not a product I feel deserves any support (and when I hear something favorable about the app, I'm always wary that it's disingenuous). Lastly, the answer is really just a glorified promo for the app and doesn't address the full scope of the question.

Comment: @cksum The OP didn't ask for a free application, and I am not affiliated with who developers the application.

Comment: I have found CleanMyMac 2 to be very easy to use and worth the price.